# Spring Boot: duplicate JSON field for superclass and subclass when using inheritance model for JSON serialization

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, jackson

I have code that follows this structure, where I have an object that has @ManyToMany mapping to a superclass. When I serialize the Person object, I get two fields in the response, "pets" and one for the cats subclass ("cats"), which are duplicates. I want to only have one field in the response, of the superclass. I.e. to have only the "pets" field, which contains information of the cats subclass. Is this possible?

```
@Entity
@Table(name="people")
public class Person {
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "owners")
    private Set<Pet> pets;
}

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class Pet {
    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "person_pets",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "pet_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "person_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private Set<Person> owners;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="cats")
public class Cat extends Pet {
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess not to use @Entity annotation on abstract class instead use @MappedSuperclass annotation.

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class Pet {
    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "person_pets",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "pet_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "person_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private Set<Person> owners;
}
```